# Elixir Install on Ubuntu 17.04 Zesty Fails

Tags: ubuntu, elixir, ubuntu-17.04

Just upgraded to Ubuntu 17.04 (zesty) and I'm having trouble installing elixir.

I installed Erlang 20.1 from their website for Ubuntu 17.04 and this install seems successful. I downloaded esl-erlang_20.1-1~ubuntu-zesty_amd64.deb then ran:

```
sudo apt-get install libsctp1
sudo dpkg -i esl-erlang_20.1-1~ubuntu~zesty_amd64.deb
sudo apt install -y esl-erlang
```

Now if enter the erlang shell and type "erlang:system_info(otp_release). i get "20"

I then went to https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/artful/universe/base/elixir and downloaded the deb and did similar steps as above to install. I also tried install elixir from apt (sudo apt-get install elixir) but all produce the same issue. I run $elixir --version and it crashes and produced a dump file.

```
> =erl_crash_dump:0.3 Sat Oct 21 12:37:40 2017 Slogan: init terminating in do_boot
> ({{badmatch,error},[{Elixir.System,build,0,[{_},{_}]},{Elixir.System,build_info,0,[{_},{_}]},{Elixir.Kernel.CLI,parse_shared,2,[{_},{_}]},{Elixir.Kernel.CLI,shared_option?,
> System version: Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.0.4] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4]
> [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [kernel-poll:false] Compiled: Fri Sep 
> 1 13:16:32 2017 Taints: erl_tracer Atoms: 7992 Calling Thread:
> scheduler:1
> =scheduler:1 Scheduler Sleep Info Flags:  Scheduler Sleep Info Aux Work: ASYNC_READY_CLEAN Current Port:  Run Queue Max Length: 0 Run
> Queue High Length: 0 Run Queue Normal Length: 1 Run Queue Low Length:
> 0 Run Queue Port Length: 0 Run Queue Flags: NONEMPTY_NORMAL |
> OUT_OF_WORK | HALFTIME_OUT_OF_WORK | NONEMPTY | EXEC Current Process:
> <0.0.0> Current Process State: Running Current Process Internal State:
> ACT_PRIO_NORMAL | USR_PRIO_NORMAL | PRQ_PRIO_NORMAL | ACTIVE | RUNNING
> | TRAP_EXIT | ON_HEAP_MSGQ Current Process Program counter:
> 0x00007fb073da8b10 (init:crash/2 + 24) Current Process CP:
> 0x0000000000000000 (i
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by compiling elixir manually.

```
mkdir $HOME/bin
cd $HOME/bin
git clone https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir.git
cd elixir
make clean test
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin/elixir/bin"
```

I'm not too sure where I was supposed to put it but this was good enough for now.

Comment: thank you, updated! I originally put the file in a directory owned by root but I moved it

Comment: I use asdf to manage erlang and elixir versions. https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf - maybe something to check out for next time :)